# Closure memory leak of unused variables

Tags: javascript

I'd like to understand under which circumstances variables which are no further used are stored in closures and lead to memory leaks. My most preferred outcome would be "there are none", but this doesn't seem to be the case.

From what I understand, once a function is declared inside another function, its internal [[scope]] is assigned the LexicalEnvironment of its encapsulating function. This LexicalEnvironment has reference local variables and the entire scope chain at that point. This basically includes **all** free variables the function could access (from what I understood of [lostechies, javascript closures explained](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/02/17/javascript-closures-explained/)).

Here the first issue arises: this should mean **all** those variables can be reached as long as the function lives. E.g. the following should already leak:

```js
function a() {
    let big = new Array(1000000).join('*'); //never accessed
    //function unused() { big; }
    return () => void 0;
}
 
let fstore = [];
function doesThisLeak() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) fstore.push(a());
}

doesThisLeak();
```

This luckily doesn't seem to be the case on my firefox. I've received several explanations to why this doesn't leak, from "the jitter is smart" to "LexicalEnvironment is a record type which means GC can collect the unused variables". I still don't know whether either is correct, whether this doesn't leak on all modern runtimes and why.

After further research, I found [auth0, four types of leaks in javascript](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/) (sadly, there appears to be no html id to jump to, the relevant part is "4: Closures") which shows a way to trick whatever smart thing is collecting the unused variables. In above snippet, when just uncommenting the "unused" function, I do not see RAM usage ever going down again (it was already noted that it could be GC simply did not run for other reasons. However, so far, I am assuming it leaks. I also got told this was limited to firefox, but it appeared to produce similar behavior in chrome)

This example (in case it really does what i believe it does), shows that completely unused variables can leak due to a function declaration in the same scope.

To conclude my problems:

1. What is the reason for, in the above snippet, "big" getting collected (when "unused" is commented) and does this happen on all modern runtimes?
2. Assuming the example with the "unused" function not commented leaks, what are best practices to avoid such accidental leaks? Are there any more? I already got the suggestion of null'ing all local variables which are not further used at the end of functions, however, this seems absurdly ugly. I fear using temporary variables for pre-calculations and accidentally leaking.

PS: It is quite hard to make certain that this question has not already been asked in the jungle of questions about memory leaks with closures.

Comment: Modern engines will keep only those variables from outer scopes actually used within the inner functions. In your case, since the returned inner function does not use `big`, no reference to it will be maintained. if instead your inner function was `return () => big;`, then yes, `big` would be maintained, but it would have to be, right? Whatever memory was involved would be GC'd anyway once `fstore` went out of scope. You can't garbage collect something which isn't garbage, and not doing so is not a "leak".

Comment: sorry what's GC again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler can examine the code of the returned function to see which free variables it references, and only those variables need to be saved in the closure, not the entire LexicalEnvironment. You can see this by examining the closure in the Javascript debugger.

```js
function a() {
  let big = new Array(1000000).join('*');
  let small = "abc"; // is accessed
  return (x) => small + x;
}

fun = a();
console.dir(fun);

function b() {
    let big = "pretend this is a really long string";
    function unused() { big; }
    return () => void 0;
}

fun = b();
console.dir(fun);
```

When you expand the first function in the debugger, you'll see `small` in the `Closure` property, but not `big`. Unfortunately, the Chrome compiler doesn't seem to be clever enough to detect when the variable is referenced in an unused function that isn't returned, so it doesn't need to be saved, so we get a leak in `b()`.

[image]

Any data that isn't saved in the closure becomes garbage and can be collected, so it won't leak.

Comment: Thanks, this solves a large portion of the problem. Issues that remain: "The compiler **can** examine", is this not by spec, can I depend on this? Also are there more pitfalls like the described one, where a reference in an unused function tricks the compiler into thinking it is needed?

Comment: It's a compiler optimization, so I don't think you can depend on it. As you've seen, it's not perfect.

Comment: As for best practices on code, any suggestions? I guess hoping for this compiler optimization to occur in all modern browsers and explicitly nulling memory-intensive non-exposed local variables when it gets more complicated is a start. Are there more known situations where this optimization fails? I'd prefer not to always have to null all variables at the end of functions.

Comment: Unless the closure is very long-lived, like an event handler, I wouldn't worry too much about it. If it's just a one-time callback, it will presumably be called pretty soon, and then discarded, so the entire closure will become garbage. And you don't have to null all variables, just the ones that are likely to consume huge amounts of memory, the rest are probably not going to cause much impact.

Comment: And don't forget: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Wait until you actually have a memory problem before worrying about this.

Answer (score 3):

After you call `a()` your `fstore` has reference to created function `() => void` only. After `a()` returns, its scope vars will be deleted. It means that no vars has reference to your `new Array(1000000).join('*')` and it will be garbage collected. It will be collected the same way if you uncomment `unused` function because it will deleted too. There are no leaks in your code.

Comment: Using chrome's debugger like Barmar said, you can see that when "unused" is uncommented, "big" is being closed over (at least in my chrome). [SS of debugger](http://i.imgur.com/CNstWe1.png)

Comment: @ASDFGerte my fail, Barmar explained this. But i think its browsers fail, it's should not be stored in closure.  If you breakpoint your `() => void 0` function execution you cant access `big` in console, it says `undefined` for me.

Answer (score 0):

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fELEK.jpg)

You can think about Javascript scope chain with the problem.Identify a Function will create a new scope chain.If function's local scope do not have a local variable, it will reference to outside scope of lexical environment, it will keep over in the memory

here's a [link](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#scope-chain)