# Javascript and memory, how is it handled?

Tags: javascript

I thought that variables were destroyed as soon as their context did not exist anymore:

```
function foo () {
    let bar = "something"
    return bar
}
```

Like in this example, I thought that `bar` was destroyed as soon as the function got executed.

But now, I discovered that you can write this in Javascript:

```
function foo () {
  let bar = "something"
  return {
    print () {
        console.log(bar)
    }
  }
}

let f = foo()

f.print();
```

This code prints "something". So I wonder now how javascript handles its memory. Why `bar` does not get destroyed at the end of the function?

Now, if I write something like:

```
function foo () {
  let bar = "something"
  let hugeVar = _.range(1,1000*1000*1000*1000) // A huge array
  return {
    print () {
        console.log(bar)
    }
  }
}
```

**Is `hugeVar` still in the memory? How Javascript decides what to keep and what not to keep?**

Comment: A variable is never destroy in Javascript: you can not destroy willingly a variable. A variable will be just increase or destroy when the browser think you do not need anymore the variable. Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963066/how-to-delete-a-variable

Comment: @GuyT: Variables don't get garbage-collected, only objects. Plus, the standard doesn't even guarantee *that*. The standard only specifies when an object is reachable or not. What to do with unreachable objects is left to the implementation. The vast majority will *not* collect an object's memory as soon as it becomes unreachable, but rather wait until there is a large number of unreachable objects and collect them in a single batch.

Comment: How memory is handled in JavaScript has nothing to do with closures.  Incorrect duplicate selected.

Comment: The last part of the question is a simplified version of [what i asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838071/closure-memory-leak-of-unused-variables). You can find your answer there.

Comment: @JörgWMittag A variable is stored somewhere in memory - as part of a scope (lexical environment) - and that will get garbage-collected like everything else. It's just not a JS object but a native one.

Answer (score 0):

It is called closure. Functions will remember those references to variables in external scopes. Read about it for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're providing it's an example of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

A **closure** is a stack frame which is allocated when a function starts its execution, and not freed after the function returns (as if a stack frame were **allocated** on the heap rather than the stack!)

A closure remembers the parent **scope**.