# How closure memory GCed?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-management

All:

I am pretty new to javascript management, when I try to understand how GC deals with closure, I run one example like:

```
function addN(n){
    var title = "ADD "+n;
    return function adder(who){
        return who+n;
    }
}
var add3 = addN(3);
var result = add3(10);
```

I wonder after addN finishes building that closure for add3, **does `title` still stay in memory, or it is just `n`?**

Another example is:

```
var globaltable = []
function addNarray(narray){
    // narray is an string array
    var titles = narray.slice(0);
    globaltable = globaltable.concat(titles);
    return function adder(who){
        return narray.join(" - ");
    }
}
```

In this example, **will that `title` get GCed**?

And I also wonder what if that narray is an array of object like `{id:0, name:"idname"}`, will the answer same?

If anyone know the answer, please share a thought, and a chrome devtool way to prove will be much appreciated, or **explain a little bit from memory usage perspective**

Thanks

Comment: Probably an interesting read: [Closure memory leak of unused variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838071/closure-memory-leak-of-unused-variables). Your example should get collected on modern browsers but this is not by spec and not necessarily so for all scenarios where it would make sense for GC to collect something.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks, so you mean on Chrome 65+. the title should be GCed?

Comment: Yes, it should be, as has also been noted in an answer already :)

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks, I have updated my question, could you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `console.dir(add3);` to see the construction of the closure. Expand the `[[Scopes]]` property, then expand the `0: Closure` object, and you'll see only:

```
n: 3
```

The closure doesn't save the value of `title` anywhere.

In the second example, the `titles` variable is still garbage collected. When you do:

```
var titles = narray.slice(0);
globaltable = globaltable.concat(titles);
```

the following happens:

1. A copy of `narray` is created by `slice()`, and stored in the local variable `titles`.
2. A new array containing the contents of `globaltable` followed by the contents of `titles`.
3. This new array is stored in `globaltable`.

At this point the old value of `globaltable` becomes garbage. And when `addNarray()` returns, the value of `titles` becomes garbage because the closure in `adder()` doesn't have any reference to it.

The strings that were in `titles` do not become garbage, because they're still referenced in `globalarray`. And `narray` doesn't become garbage because it's references in the `adder` closure.

Basically, a closure should *only* hold onto references to variables that are mentioned somewhere in the function being returned. Other variables in the outer scope do not need to be saved.

The basic principle of garbage collection is simple: If there's no way to access a piece of data, it can be collected as garbage. There are sometimes bugs in the implementation, but as a general rule you can assume this is true.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that narray is an string array, is the answer still same?

Comment: It makes no difference. There's no reference to the variable `title` in the `adder` function, so it's not saved in the closure.

Comment: `narray` is saved, `title` isn't.

Comment: Silly me, I was thinking of `globaltable.push()`, not `globaltable.concat()`.

Comment: thanks. I am curious in terms of memory usage, Is my understanding about the whole process correct: first, narray.slice(0) copy the whole string array into another array in heap(make titles points to it), then copy again by globaltable.concat(reassign globaltable points to it), does it mean now there should be 2 string arrays inside the heap: the memory pointed by titles gets GCed, the memory pointed by narray keeps, the memory pointed by globaltable keeps? if narray takes 10 space, after running addNarray, there will be 20 space used in memory?

Comment: Thanks so much. Just want to confirm my understanding: there are two arrays size memory space used. Is it correct? size of narray, size of old globatable size + narray size.