# Memory leaks avoiding with Function.prototype.bind?

Tags: javascript

It's commonly advised to use a named function as a callback of an asynchronous operation instead of directly passing anonymous one to there. This approach sometimes prevents memory leaks:

```
function performAsyncOperation() { 
  let heavyVariable = new Heavy();  
  lib.asyncOperation(param, function (err, data) { /* some code here */ });
}
```

In this sample the anonymous callback remembers `heavyVariable`, and probably we don't need it.

```
  function callback(err, data) { /* some code here */ }

  function performAsyncOperation() { 
      let heavyVariable = new Heavy();  
      lib.asyncOperation(param, callback);
  }
```

Here we've dispensed with memory leaks of such type.

It's all very well, until our callback needs some additional parameter that is received from the `performAsyncOperation` environment. In such case we could adopt something like this:

```
lib.asyncOperation(param, (err, data) => { callback(additionalParam, err, data) });
```

But obviously it amounts to the first case (the arrow function will store its outer environment in the same way).

The only option I can come up with is to use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
lib.asyncOperation(param, callback.bind(this, additionalParam));
```

However, this approach dooms to decline code readability because the code reader might start to go over in their mind why the author commited it here.

So are there some elegant approaches to address this issue? And do we need them at all? I mean probably a JS implementation (browser, Node.js) takes responsibility for all this work and effectively does not store `heavyVariable` in memory?

Comment: Where do you get that information from? 
The Garbage Collector should take care of these things.
In fact, if you reference anywhere not needed stuff, it gets not cleaned/collected.
But this has nothing to do with "bind"/anonymous callbacks or similar.
Maybe im wrong and in details your right, if so you have a bigger problem.

Comment: In modern engines, local variables, which a function closes over, but doesn't use, are [typically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838071/closure-memory-leak-of-unused-variables) (note: 5 years old, potentially changed) not kept, but free for garbage collection. If you need to run on ancient engines, you'll have a lot of other problems (e.g. how to make sure, that transpilers don't change your meticulously fine-tuned code). Therefore, as noted in the linked question, i'd go by "premature optimization is the root of all evil" first, and solve individual problem-cases on demand.