# How to use FinalizationRegistry to clear interval inside a class constructor when object is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I have this code created with help from ChatGPT:

```js
class Thing {
    #intervalId;
    #finalizationRegistry;
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor()');
        let count = 0;
        this.#intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(`Test ${count++}`);
        }, 1000);

        this.#finalizationRegistry = new FinalizationRegistry(() => {
            this.#destructor();
        });
        this.#finalizationRegistry.register(this);
    }
    #destructor() {
        console.log('destructor()');
        clearInterval(this.#intervalId);
    }
}

(() => {
    const x = new Thing();
})();
```

This is my attempt to create a destructor for a class in JavaScript. I'm not sure if it works because the `console.log('destructor()');` was not called when I tested. My first code used a dummy object inside the constructor as a help value and that was working, it was triggering when I assigned `x = null` but the code was wrong.

The above code is just the smallest possible example of clearing setInterval with `FinalizationRegistry` but I'm not sure if it works.

Is there a way to test that this actually works and call destructor?

My real question is that I want to implement Cache class and I need to trigger this function inside interval:

```js
this.#intervalId = setInterval(() => {
   this.#prune();
}, 1000);
```

And I want to clear the timer when this is not accessible anymore. Like with the above code:

```js
(() => {
    const x = new Thing();
})();
```

Can you create an interval inside the class constructor that references `this` and clear the interval when the object is garbage collected? Can the object even be garbage collected when intervals keep a reference to this? If not then is there a workaround?

Comment: "*Can the object even be garbage collected when intervals keep a reference to this?*" - No! "*If not then is there a workaround?*" - you'll need a weak reference

Comment: "*I have this code created with help from ChatGPT*" - this is horrible. Create a single "global" finalisation registry, not one per instance.

Comment: @Bergi ok, but you know how to write the code to trigger `console.log('destructor()');`? Also, do you think that the GC is not triggered because intervals have `this` in closure? This is just something that came into my mind now.

Comment: "*do you think that the GC is not triggered because intervals have this in closure?*" - yes.  It's a bit weird since the one closure (that actually keeps it alive) doesn't actually use `this`, but afaik [this is a limitation of the closure implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38838071/1048572) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328761/1048572)). A heap snapshot and retainer analysis seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I originally failed to address OP's second point, and now I rewrote the answer. See the original in the edit history.)

To access a method from the inverval, you may not use `this` directly, because that would keep the object alive, and the destructor would never run.

Instead, you have to use a `WeakRef` to `this`. That way, you don't even need a `FinalizationRegistry`, because you can clear the interval *from the interval itself* when the object is dropped.

```js
class Thing {
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor()');

        let count = 0;
        const weakRef = new WeakRef(this);

        //Using a `function` to explicitly prevent access to `this`:
        const intervalId = setInterval(function (){
            console.log(`Test ${count++}`);

            const self = weakRef.deref();

            if(self) {
                self.#prune();
            } else {
                console.log('clearInterval()');
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    #prune(){
        console.log('prune()');
    }
}

new Thing();
```

Comment: I'd probably get rid of the "`#destructor`" entirely (`static` or not) and only pass an anonymous callback to the `FinalizationRegistry` constructor

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I guess you could do that too. (I started from OP's code and left it in.)

Comment: The static destructor is not actually a destructor. It's the same as normal code outside of class. And this was not the code written by chatGPT, it was rewritten by me. I only wanted to know how to use `FinalizationRegistry` since it was not clear for me from MDN how to use it.

Comment: @jcubic "The static destructor is not actually a destructor." -- What do you mean by that?

Comment: @FZs real destructor needs to have access to `this` otherwise, it's just a method named destructor.

Comment: @jcubic Yes, that's in part what I meant by "JS doesn't have proper destructors". But you can expose whatever properties of the original object to it by including them in the testament.

Comment: This is the same as a `function destructor() {}` outside the class, there is no benefit of having it as a static field inside the class.

Comment: @jcubic Yes. I don't insist on keeping it a static method, you may inline it as Bergi suggested, move it outside of the class or whatever. Heck, you might even keep it an instance method and avoid accessing `this` inside (though I'd advise against doing that). I'm not trying to say it is special in any way. I made it `static` because that seemed to be the closest to what you had in the OP. (And because this makes it more encapsulated, tied to your class, not accessible from outside.)

Comment: Ok, thanks it's almost the same as my answer but you don't have code that handles `this.#intervalId = setInterval(() => { this.#prune(); }, 1000);` which was in my question. `this` inside interval needs to be handled on its own. See my answer.

Comment: @jcubic I see. Seems like I misunderstood the point of the question, and addressed only the destructor part, not the "how do you call a method on the object without keeping it alive". Sorry.

Comment: @jcubic Btw, I realized that with a `WeakRef`, you don't even need a `FinalizationRegistry` at all.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include that approach, but feel free to accept yours and I can delete mine if you feel like that's more fair.

Comment: interesting, fewer mechanisms are always better.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this with hints from @Bergi:

```js
const finalizationRegistry = new FinalizationRegistry(interval => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('destructor()');
});

class Thing {
    #intervalId;
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor()');
        let count = 0;
        const ref = new WeakRef(this);
        this.#intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            const self = ref.deref();
            if (self) {
                self.prune(`test ${count++}`);
            }
        }, 1000);
        finalizationRegistry.register(this, this.#intervalId);
    }
    prune(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

(() => {
    const x = new Thing();
})();


if (global.gc) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        global.gc();
    }, 5000);
} else {
    console.log('Garbage collection unavailable.  Pass --expose-gc '
      + 'when launching node to enable forced garbage collection.');
}
```

I used WeakRef since I needed to call the `#prune` method (as stated in the question) since without `this` kept inside the function and the object was never garbage collected.

It works in NodeJS when called with `node --expose-gc script.js`.

Note that I think that real destructor is not possible and you need to have the code that clean up the class like clear of interval outside of the class.